# how to use ggplot2 make recursive partitioning survival tree

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

can everyone tell me how to use ggplot2 make recursive partitioning survival tree?

I know " party "  package can make a plot in R, however the plot is not looking good, and all the plots in the rest of my report are made by ggplot2.

for my plot,  I printsreen and added labels manually. if there is a way to input data and plot in R also works, Thanks!!

Comment: Probably better to ask on stats.stackexchange.com . Also, most of us will have no idea what a recursive partitioning survival tree is, can you post a link to an image or explanation?

Comment: Thanks smci, I posted the question on stachexchange.com . The plot looks like a regression tree, but instant of of using binary variable, this, tree is for censored data

Comment: and here is a link of my plot http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110774/how-to-use-ggplot2-make-recursive-partitioning-survival-tree

Comment: Just using `ggplot` doesn't mean it will magically look good. What specifically don't you like about the way `party` draws trees? What is your input data? Are you fitting a model of some sort?

Comment: Based on experience you'll get a better answer on stats.stackexchange.com; crossposting is frowned upon, so this version should probably be migrated & closed.

Comment: The plot you've linked doesn't look lie a survival tree plot at all, so I'm not sure I understand your question. Anyhow, the `party` package plots can be modified and made pritier, see [here](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=party/man/panelfunctions.Rd&d=R_CC)

Comment: @MrFlick , thanks,I don't like the size, font, color etc of the plots.  my input data is raw data : some observations with several variables, and then I fit a regression tree and got a plot . I was thinking either modify the tree plot or get the data/table after I fit the regression tree and make my own ploy by using ggplot2

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, David. that helps, I will start from it to see if I can make a better tree